# How to reduce polycount for game objects?

Tags: blender

I am an intermediate in Blender, and I have always noticed that as the polycount increases to more than 20,000 polygons, Blender starts to slow down and I am not able to sculpt properly.

My PC is pretty powerful:

- i5 2500 processor
- 8GB RAM
- Radeon 7770HD dedicated graphics card

---

Does this mean that the poly count of all the games needs to be less than 20,000?

If not, than how can I reduce the polycount, and what should be the average polycount for all the game objects?

Comment: -1 There are so many things wrong with this question: polycount for a game depends on the game and platform, we don't have a clue about what you're doing, this seems to be a question about _blender_ only and should be more precised and asked on [blender.se].

Comment: This may be a subjective thing, but I wouldn't consider that PC powerful at all.

Comment: The entities of most games are around 8000 triangles, so yes, that is absurdly high.

Comment: you have low to mid range parts so you PC isn't that powerful, blender should be able to render many more polys than 20,000. I'm thinking its more a problem with your rig. I use Max for all my 3d modeling stuff and sometime I draft my game world in Max just to see how it looks before I put it in engine so I end up with 100's of thousands if not millions of polys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does this mean that the polycount of all the games needs to be lesser than 20k?

Certanly not, there are games that render millions of triangles per frame. [1]

The other part of your question is somewhat harder to answer without more knowledge of target platform or type of game. For say, third-person shooters, characters are in the center of view most of the time and can have 10k triangles or more.

Most geometry in games have multiple levels of detail as well, so the futher away the are from the camera the smaller number of pixels they represent on screen, so we use simplified geometry. Same applies to textures.

I shouldn't worry about blender slowing down while modeling your assets, use your assets in an game engine and go from there.

[1] - http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/uncharted-2-mastering-the-cell-blog-entry